# Where can I find a good template for a software application user guide?

Tags: coding-style, user-guide

Looking for links to resources that will help me write a user guide for a software application. I'm after something that will help me to structure my guide, give it an appropriate writing style, and ensure that it has an excellent look and feel throughout.

Comment: Some indication of your user base might help. Could it be anyone, or are they likely to be developers/technically minded?

Comment: Some indication of the kind of software you're writing would help.  If your software, for example, is like Microsoft Word, then it would be easy to suggest a user guide template.

Answer (score 2):

This link has some strong points. Each point is presented with clear speech and with inline justifications.

> When writing procedures, use the
>   active voice (e.g. Click this) and
>   address users directly (write "you"
>   rather than "the user").
>
> When explaining an action, use the
>   "command" form of the verb:
>
> "Choose an option from the menu and
>   press [ENTER]."

http://www.klariti.com/technical-writing/User-Guides-Tutorial.shtml

Here is the complete list of the topics covered on the aforementioned article:

- Front Page (cover pages)
- Cover and Title Page
- Disclaimer
- Preface
- Contents
- Body of the guide
- Procedures
- Writing procedures
- Chunking text
- Number your steps
- Using the If-Then Approach
- Reference Materials
- Back Matter
- Glossary
- Index
- Establishing Standards
- Document Format
- Structure Style
- Technical Language
- Addressing the User
- Presenting your material
- Special Requirements

Answer (score 0):

For structure and look+feel, consider using a framework such as DocBook.

DocBook uses an XML markup schema that makes you think about how your document should be arranged.  There are XSL transformations to convert it to common formats like HTML and PDF with a whole load of config options to make it look the way you want. And it's open-source (free). There are downsides of course: the schema's pretty big, and editing can be hard work without a good XML editor.

Examples: http://wiki.docbook.org/topic/WhoUsesDocBook